# TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for <KerasTensor when using tf.map_fn and keras functional model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I attempt to use tf.map_fn in the definition of a keras Functional model, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for <KerasTensor: ...
```

e.g. this simple model will trigger that error in tf-nightly 2.5.0 :

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

x = Input(shape=(10,))

y = tf.map_fn(lambda x : x * 2, x, fn_output_signature=tf.float32)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
```

Whereas replacing the call to tf.map_fn to calls to other tensorflow operations works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to result from tf.map_fn being unable to determine the TypeSpec of the input tensor when the input is a keras sympolic Input.

Several times now I've run into problems with tensorflow ops and Keras symbolic Input tensors. Wrapping the offending code in a custom layer seems to generally fix it.

For example, replacing the code above with this will execute successfully:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Layer
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

x = Input(shape=(10,))

class MapLayer(Layer):

    def call(self, input):
        return tf.map_fn(lambda x : x * 2, input, fn_output_signature=tf.float32)

y = MapLayer()(x)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `tf.keras.layers.Lambda` layer instead?

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

x = Input(shape=(10,))

y = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x : x * 2)(x)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
```

Comment: Ah yes, it seems Lambda will work as well! Though my issue was needing to use `tf.map_fn` so you'd need to change call to: 

`y = Lambda(lambda x : tf.map_fn(lambda y : y * 2, x, fn_output_signature=tf.float32))(x)`

which is a bit hard to read but it works! (I understand that in this example above `tf.map_fn` is not actually needed but that was just a minimal example). Seems like for simple calls to the mapping function your lambda approach is simpler, for more involved ones perhaps the custom layer is cleaner.