# How to use 'Keras symbolic inputs' with 'tf.while_loop'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to create N x N tensor using tf.while_loop in my custom Keras layer. Here, N (`timesteps` in code) is a Keras symbolic tensor (integer scalar). The below code is `__call__` method of my custom Keras layer in Functional Model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

# timesteps = tf.constant(7) ## This makes this code work!!
timesteps = K.shape(inputs)[1] ## Or equivalently provided by timesteps = keras.layers.Input(shape= (), batch_size= 1, name= "timesteps")
# timesteps = tf.convert_to_tensor(timesteps) ## Does not work.
idx_outer = tf.constant(0)
timesteps_mixed_outer = tf.reshape(tf.Variable([]), (0, timesteps))
# timesteps_mixed_outer = Lambda(lambda timesteps : tf.reshape(tf.Variable([]), (0, timesteps)))(timesteps) ## Does not work
def body_inner(idx_inner, idx_outer, timesteps_mixed_inner):
    timesteps_mixed_inner = tf.concat([timesteps_mixed_inner, [tf.cond(idx_inner == idx_outer, lambda : True, lambda : False)]], axis = 0)
    return idx_inner + 1, idx_outer, timesteps_mixed_inner

def body_outer(idx_outer, timesteps_mixed_outer):
    timesteps_mixed_inner = tf.Variable([])
    idx_inner = tf.constant(0)

    idx_inner, idx_outer, timesteps_mixed_inner = tf.while_loop(lambda idx_inner, idx_outer, timesteps_mixed_inner: K.less(idx_inner, timesteps), body_inner, [idx_inner, idx_outer, timesteps_mixed_inner], shape_invariants= [idx_inner.get_shape(), idx_outer.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None])])

    timesteps_mixed_outer = tf.concat([timesteps_mixed_outer, [timesteps_mixed_inner]], axis = 0)
    return idx_outer + 1, timesteps_mixed_outer

idx_outer, timesteps_mixed_outer = tf.while_loop(lambda idx_outer, timesteps_mixed_outer: K.less(idx_outer, timesteps), body_outer, [idx_outer, timesteps_mixed_outer], shape_invariants= [idx_outer.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None, None])]) ## Here raises error
```

The last line of above code raises the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
Could not build a TypeSpec for <KerasTensor: shape=(0, None) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'tf.reshape')> with type KerasTensor
```

**What I have tried:**

- I suspected the problem is came from Keras symbolic tensor input 'timesteps', so I have changed to `timesteps = tf.constant(7)` for experimental purpose. Then the code works and 'timesteps_mixed_outer' has the desired values:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(7, 7), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

- I suspected the problem comes the use of from Keras symbolic tensor `timesteps` in `tf.reshape` function, so I have initialized `timesteps_mixed_outer = tf.reshape(tf.Variable([]), (0, 7))` and leave `timesteps = K.shape(inputs)[1]`. Then new error occurs:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement `__len__`. You may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model. This error will also get raised if you try asserting a symbolic input/output directly.
```

- I have also tried to wrap tf.reshape following two solutions suggested in [TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for <KerasTensor when using tf.map_fn and keras functional model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65809906/typeerror-could-not-build-a-typespec-for-kerastensor-when-using-tf-map-fn-and), but both raise the same error.

**My environments is as follows:**

- MacOS 12.0.1
- Python 3.7.3
- keras-preprocessing [installed: 1.1.2]
- `keras.__version__ == 2.4.3`
- tensorflow [installed: 2.4.1]

  - tensorflow-estimator [installed: 2.4.0]

## EDIT

This error is raised when I build Keras model, before feeding actual Numpy values. `timesteps = K.shape(inputs)[1]` is varying across inputs, so it is set to `None` as like a batch dimension.

```
timesteps = K.shape(inputs)[1]
== 
<KerasTensor: shape=() dtype=int32 inferred_value=[None] (created by layer 'tf.__operators__.getitem_6')>
==
dtype:tf.int32
is_tensor_like:True
name:'tf.__operators__.getitem_6/strided_slice:0'
op:'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/Users/imgspoints/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py", line 193, in _get_py_dictionary\n    attr = getattr(var, name)\n  File "/Users/imgspoints/.local/share/virtualenvs/experiments-m6CLaaa4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/keras_tensor.py", line 251, in op\n    raise TypeError(\'Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not \'\nTypeError: Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement `op`. You may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.\n'
shape:TensorShape([])
type_spec:TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)
_inferred_value:[None]
_keras_history:KerasHistory(layer=<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.SlicingOpLambda object at 0x1774fac88>, node_index=0, tensor_index=0)
_name:'tf.__operators__.getitem_6/strided_slice:0'
_overload_all_operators:<bound method KerasTensor._overload_all_operators of <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>>
_overload_operator:<bound method KerasTensor._overload_operator of <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>>
_to_placeholder:<bound method KerasTensor._to_placeholder of <KerasTensor: shape=() dtype=int32 inferred_value=[None] (created by layer 'tf.__operators__.getitem_6')>>
_type_spec:TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)
```

When the error is raised, `K.less(idx_outer, timesteps)` can be evaluated succesfully:

`timesteps == <KerasTensor: shape=() dtype=bool (created by layer 'tf.math.less')>`
So I believe the error comes from `tf.concat` and I'm now trying to replace `tf.concat` to another operation (e.g. Keras Concatenate layer).

## Simpler Example

The following codes work when `end = tf.constant(7)` but raises

```
Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement `__len__`. You may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model. This error will also get raised if you try asserting a symbolic input/output directly.
```

error at `_, final_output = tf.while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars=[step, output])` when `end = Input(shape= (), batch_size= 1, name= "timesteps", dtype= tf.int32)`.

```
mport tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Input

# end = Input(shape= (), batch_size= 1, name= "timesteps", dtype= tf.int32) ## not works :(
end = tf.constant(7) ## works :)
array = tf.Variable([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
step = tf.constant(0)
output = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)

def cond(step, output):
    return step < end

def body(step, output):
    output = output.write(step, tf.gather(array, step))
    return step + 1, output

_, final_output = tf.while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars=[step, output])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your logic in a custom layer and using `tf` operations:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()
              
  def call(self, inputs):

    input_shape = tf.shape(inputs)
    end = input_shape[-1]
    array = tf.ones((input_shape[-1],))
    step = tf.constant(0)
    output = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)

    def cond(step, output):
        return step < end

    def body(step, output):
        output = output.write(step, tf.gather(array, step))
        return step + 1, output

    _, final_output = tf.while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars=[step, output])
    return tf.reshape(final_output.stack(), (input_shape))


inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape= (None, ), batch_size= 1, name= "timesteps", dtype= tf.int32)
cl = CustomLayer()
outputs = cl(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
random_data = tf.random.uniform((1, 7), dtype=tf.int32, maxval=50)
print(model(random_data))
```

```
tf.Tensor([1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.], shape=(7,), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice @AlongTogether, your codes work well in my custom layer when I replace your `inputs` with my real `inputs`. Now I'm working on restructuring my codes (nested while_loop) following your codes.

Answer (score 0):

timesteps_mixed_outer = tf.concat([timesteps_mixed_outer, [timesteps_mixed_inner]], axis = 0)

You have to check the shape of timesteps_mixed_outer and timesteps_mixed_inner. try to change the axis value.

or try this.

```
timesteps_mixed_outer = tf.concat([timesteps_mixed_outer.numpy(), timesteps_mixed_inner.numpy()], axis = 0)
```

Comment: Thank for answering my question! I have tried 4 cases by trying axis = 0 or 1 for both  of tf.concat, but the same error is raised. And because the code works fine when I set `timesteps = tf.constant(7)`, I believe `axis` in `tf.concat` is not a cause of problem.  I have also tried `.numpy()` for `timesteps_mixed_outer` and `timesteps_mixed_inner`, but the same error is raised. Because the actual value of `timesteps` and shape of timesteps_mixed_outer are not decided in build time, I think .numpy() cannot be calculated in build time. This is when I build computation graph.